# expected begin_array but was begin_object at line 1 column 2 path $ or api token implementation

Tags: java, android-studio, retrofit, token

i search about this error, found few solutions but they didnt work. Or i couldnt implement at all. I think my problem is pharmacy class not enough. I need one more class for turning object to array. Or maybe my api token implementation doesnt work.
This is my json :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "result": [
        {
            "name": "Umut Eczanesi",
            "dist": "Beykoz",
            "address": "Kavacık Mah. Fatih Sultan Mehmet Cad. No:28/2 Kavacık",
            "phone": "0216 680 00 46",
            "loc": "41.0934997377573,29.0904339186627"
        }
     ]
}
```

This is my main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context = this;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        EditText theFilter = findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);

        OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(
                        new Interceptor() {
                            @Override
                            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                        .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                                        .addHeader("authorization","myapikeywashere").build();
                                return chain.proceed(request);
                            }
                        }).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(defaultHttpClient)
                .build();
        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

        Call<List<Pharmacy>> call = api.getPharmacies();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Pharmacy>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Pharmacy>> call, Response<List<Pharmacy>> response) {
                List<Pharmacy> pharmacies = response.body();
                ArrayList<String> pharmacyNames= new ArrayList<>();

                for(int i=0;i<pharmacies.size();i++){
                    pharmacyNames.add(pharmacies.get(i).getName());
                }
                List<HashMap<String,String>> listItems = new ArrayList<>();

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                theFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        (MainActivity.this).adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Pharmacy>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

My api class:

```
public interface Api {
    String BASE_URL = "https://api.collectapi.com/health/";

    @GET("dutyPharmacy?il=Istanbul")
    Call<List<Pharmacy>> getPharmacies ();

}
```

And pharmacy model class :

```
public class Pharmacy {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("dist")
    @Expose
    private String dist;
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("phone")
    @Expose
    private String phone;
    @SerializedName("loc")
    @Expose
    private String loc;

    public Pharmacy(String name, String dist, String address,String phone, String loc) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dist = dist;
        this.address = address;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.loc = loc;

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getDist() {
        return dist;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem. Im putting it here so maybe it help someone else.
I created a Result class because of Json Result[]:

```
public class Result {
    @SerializedName("result")
    @Expose
    private List<Pharmacy> result;

    public Result(List<Pharmacy> result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public List<Pharmacy> getResult(){
        return result;
    }
}
```

So MainActivity has some changes too:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context = this;
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        EditText theFilter = findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);

        OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(
                        new Interceptor() {
                            @Override
                            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                                        .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
                                        .addHeader("authorization","apikeywashere").build();
                                return chain.proceed(request);
                            }
                        }).build();
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Api.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(defaultHttpClient)
                .build();
        Api api = retrofit.create(Api.class);

        Call<Result> call = api.getPharmacies();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<Result>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Result> call, Response<Result> response) {
                List<Pharmacy> pharmacies = response.body().getResult();
                ArrayList<String> pharmacyNamesAndAddresses= new ArrayList<>();

                for(int i=0;i<pharmacies.size();i++){
                    pharmacyNamesAndAddresses.add(pharmacies.get(i).getName()+ " " + pharmacies.get(i).getAddress());
                }

                adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,pharmacyNamesAndAddresses);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                theFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        (MainActivity.this).adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Result> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and api class has changes too:

```
public interface Api {
    String BASE_URL = "https://api.collectapi.com/health/";

    @GET("dutyPharmacy?il=Istanbul")
    Call<Result> getPharmacies ();

}
```